Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException
I am working on vulnerabilities and have upgraded spring-webmvc version to 6.1.13 to resolve them
Here is my pom(omitted the dependencies which are not important in this context)
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jvm.options>-Dspring.profiles.active=stage</jvm.options>
        <version.spock>2.3-groovy-3.0</version.spock>
        <version.groovy>3.0.9</version.groovy>
     
        <spring-security.version>6.2.7</spring-security.version>
        <spring-webflux.version>6.1.13</spring-webflux.version>
        <spring-webmvc.version>6.1.13</spring-webmvc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- CVE-2024-38816 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-webflux.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- CVE-2024-38816 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-webmvc.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      
        <!-- ADDED THIS FOR VALIDATION TO WORK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!--Spock 3 runs in Junit5 BUT we arent there yet, so have to force it to go back to Junit4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spock}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${version.groovy}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${version.groovy}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-datetime</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${version.groovy}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spock}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

After running mvn clean package, i am getting following error
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.13.1:compileTests (default) on project a-services: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.13.1:compileTests (default) on project a-services: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.

Stacktrace
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.13.1:compileTests (default) on project admin-services: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.13.1:compileTests (default) on project admin-services: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:903)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:280)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:203)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:41)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.CompileTestsMojo.execute (CompileTestsMojo.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:903)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:280)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:203)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.AbstractCompileMojo.doCompile (AbstractCompileMojo.java:334)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.CompileTestsMojo.execute (CompileTestsMojo.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:903)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:280)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:203)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidationException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass (AsmReferenceResolver.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType (AsmReferenceResolver.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType (AsmReferenceResolver.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode (MemberSignatureParser.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lambda$createMethodNode$1 (DecompiledClassNode.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode (DecompiledClassNode.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers (DecompiledClassNode.java:203)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods (DecompiledClassNode.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods (ClassNode.java:865)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecialMethodCall.checkIsConditionBlock (SpecialMethodCall.java:269)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecialMethodCall.parse (SpecialMethodCall.java:172)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitMethodCallExpression (AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit (MethodCallExpression.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBinaryExpression (CodeVisitorSupport.java:202)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitBinaryExpression (AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:166)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.doVisitBinaryExpression (DeepBlockRewriter.java:127)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitBinaryExpression (AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:111)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visitDeclarationExpression (DeepBlockRewriter.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit (DeclarationExpression.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement (CodeVisitorSupport.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement (ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:200)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitExpressionStatement (AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:162)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visitInteractionAwareExpressionStatement (DeepBlockRewriter.java:96)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.doVisitExpressionStatement (DeepBlockRewriter.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitExpressionStatement (AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit (ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.StatementReplacingVisitorSupport.replace (StatementReplacingVisitorSupport.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visit (AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visit (DeepBlockRewriter.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecRewriter.visitAnyBlock (SpecRewriter.java:405)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.WhenBlock.accept (WhenBlock.java:32)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.Method.accept (Method.java:70)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.Spec.accept (Spec.java:112)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.processSpec (SpockTransform.java:76)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.visit (SpockTransform.java:63)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform.visit (SpockTransform.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.lambda$addPhaseOperationsForGlobalTransforms$4 (ASTTransformationVisitor.java:337)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation (CompilationUnit.java:901)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations (CompilationUnit.java:671)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile (CompilationUnit.java:635)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile (CompilationUnit.java:610)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.AbstractCompileMojo.doCompile (AbstractCompileMojo.java:334)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.CompileTestsMojo.execute (CompileTestsMojo.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:903)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:280)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:203)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:41)

Here is the gmaven plugin config
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

I tried upgrading gmavenplus-plugin to new versions but it is still giving the same error,
Do i need to upgrade groovy or any other dependencies to match with 6.1.13 spring-webmvc,

Don't upgrade parts of Spring, that is trouble waiting to happen. You will endup with incompatible jars and classes. Upgrade Spring Boot instead.

Thanks @M.Deinum, i have upgraded parent to 3.3.5, the issue is resolved
